# AndEngine and onAreaTouched for a series of sprites

Tags: android, andengine

I have some thing like this

```
int height = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < powerBarUnits.size(); i++) {
    final PowerBar powerBar = powerBarUnits.get(i);

    lastest_y += (height);
    powerBar.sprite = new AnimatedSprite(
        (CAMERA_WIDTH - 50), lastest_y,
        powerBar.texture) {

    @Override
    public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
            float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

            switch (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction()) {

                    case TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

                        powerBar.changeTileIndex();
                    }
                    }
                    return false;
                }

            };

            mScene.registerTouchArea(powerBar.sprite);
            this.mScene.attachChild(powerBar.sprite);

            lastest_y += 10;
        }
```

Now each powerBar is simple rectangular of size 68x10 what I wan't is that on touch of each powerBar unit it should change its tile index (This logic is implemented).

But the onAreaTouched gets invoked only for 1st powerBar unit and its not getting updated rest of the series.

What can I do so that the touch event is distributed through the entire series of powerBar untis ?

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to propagate the touch events to the other powerBar units. Maybe have a class (lets just call it PowerBarController) that holds a reference to each of your powerBar units, and have your individual powerBar units invoke a callback method on PowerBarController informing which unit was touched. Then your PowerBarController can invoke changeTileIndex for the affected sprites instead.